# Add Image Blob to Existing Array And Update State

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi I am trying to async load a blob image from a string and then enter that image into an already existing array that maps said image out as an img tag.

After going back and forth for a few hours now, i'm going to try to see if i can even understand how to ask the question. I've isolated the problem to this, in order to render the image how I want through the method I have, i have to effectively remove any other onChange updating that array from the form.

What I need is string reference to image => if image exists when you do the on change add this bit that is a jsx tag with the image => map the array with the jsx tag in another component => update the same array with information that manipulates the image without removing the image from the object.

Using the onclick and having no other onchange method in the form and then sort of unlocking one of my maps will ultimately show the image on the screen, so its nothing in the back end its just making this stupid map make sense to itself. I apologize in advance for the code...

```
  const sectionImg = {
    name: "",
    sectionArea: "",
    alt: "",
    background: "",
    code: "",
    height: "",
    width: "",
    sectionOrdinality: 0,
  };

const [img, setImg] = useState([...sectionImg]);
```

I removed part of the code for brevity but map over

```
        {img.map((row, i) => {
          let delCheck = 1;
          const index = img.findIndex((x) => x === row);
           
          return (
            <div
              style={{ width: "200px" }}
              key={i}
              className='row card bg-dark'>
              <h3>{row.sectionArea} Image</h3>
              {Object.keys(row).map((key) => (
                <div>
                  <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                    {key === "sectionArea" ? (
                      <select
                        name='sectionArea'
                        onChange={(e) => onChangeImg2(i, e)}>
                        <option>Section Position...</option>
                        <option value='topLeft'>Top Left</option>
                        <option value='topCenter'>Top Center</option>
                        <option value='topRight'>Top Right</option>
                        <option value='middleRight'>Middle Right</option>
                        <option value='middleCenter'>Middle Center</option>
                        <option value='middleLeft'>Middle Left</option>
                        <option value='bottomRight'>Bottom Right</option>
                        <option value='bottomCenter'>Bottom Center</option>
                        <option value='bottomLeft'>Bottom Left</option>
                      </select>
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}

                    {key === "background" && pallet ? (
                      <select
                        name='background'
                        onChange={(e) => onChangeImg2(i, e)}>
                        <option>Background Color...</option>
                        <option value={pallet.primary}>Primary</option>
                        <option value={pallet.dark}>Dark</option>
                        <option value={pallet.light}>Light</option>
                        <option value={pallet.danger}>Danger</option>
                        <option value={pallet.primary}>Success</option>
                      </select>
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}

                    {key === "name" ? (
                      <div className='grid-2'>
                        <input
                          type='text'
                          placeholder='name...'
                          value={row[key]}
                          name={key}
                        />

                        <span style={{ float: "right" }}>
                          <button
                            type='button'
                            className='btn btn-sm'
                            onClick={(e) => {
                              getContentImage(currentContent);
                              onChangeImg(i, e, currentContent);
                              clearCurrentContent();
                            }}>
                            Add Content
                          </button>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
                    {key === "width" ? (
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Width'
                        value={row[key]}
                        name={key}
                        onChange={(e) => onChangeImg2(i, e)}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
                    {key === "height" ? (
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Height'
                        value={row[key]}
                        name={key}
                        onChange={(e) => onChangeImg2(i, e)}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
                  </form>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

```
   const {image} = useContext(imageContext)
  const onChangeImg = (i, e, currentContent) => {
    
    const { value, name } = e.currentTarget;
    let newResults = [...img];

    if (typeof currentContent === "string" && image !== null) {
      newResults[i] = {
        ...newResults[i],
        ["name"]: currentContent,
        code: (
          <img
            src={URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([image], { type: "img/png" }))}
            alt=''
          />
        ),
      };
      setImg(newResults);
    }
  };

  const onChangeImg2 = (i, e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.currentTarget;
    let newResults = [...img];

    newResults[i] = {
      ...newResults[i],
      [name]: value,
    };

    console.log(newResults[i]);

    // setImg(newResults);
  };
```

```
              {img
                .filter((h) => h.name != "")
                .filter((h) => h.sectionArea === "topLeft")
                .map(({ code }) => code)}
```

Comment: "Trying to async load a blob image from a string" What does that mean? What is `image` in `new Blob([image]...`? If a string, it won't do what you want. The Blob constructor when given strings will encode these strings as UTF8 and push this UTF8 text into the Blob's data. An image is binary data, UTF8 can't represent some characters in there, and your resulting Blob will be broken.

Comment: okay i didnt want to get the entire backend part out, but image is the arraybuffer returned from getContentImage(currentContent) which is stored in the ImageState